# itext 7 - how to configure table splitting

Tags: itext, itext7

I have a couple of issues with tables rendered with itext 7. I use itext 7.0.2.2 (C# edition).

First, when table starts close to the bottom of the page and page has space only for header, itext 7 renders header on the first page, and page breaks right after header. How to force keeping header and the first row together?
[image: table splits right after header]

Next issue is that itext 7 splits row instead of moving whole row to the next page. I know itext 5 have setSplitLate(bool) method that configures itext to split row or not, but what to do with itext 7? See what's happens with row:
[image: table row breaks]
Note that row can be empty and should have minimum height, so setKeepTogether(true) on cell's content is not a solution. I add cells this way:

```
table.AddCell(new Cell().SetMinHeight(MIN_HEIGHT).Add("foo"));
```

**UPDATE:**
Here is a repro for row splitting (C#):

```
var writer = new PdfWriter(new FileStream("...", FileMode.Create));
var pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer);
using (var document = new Document(pdfDoc, PageSize.A4))
{
    var table = new iText.Layout.Element.Table(UnitValue.CreatePercentArray(new[] { 1.3f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f }))
                .SetWidthPercent(100f)
                .SetFixedLayout();
    foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(1, 7 * 100)) // 100 rows
    {
        var cell = new Cell().SetKeepTogether(true).SetMinHeight(45).Add(i.ToString());
        table.AddCell(cell);
    }
    document.Add(table);
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Hmm, why `setKeepTogether(true)` is not a solution?

Comment: Header issue is indeed something that should be improved in iText7. As a workaround, you can add an `AreaBreak` before the problematic table. But that's not a generic solution of course.

Comment: setKeepTogether(true) doesn't work for cells:
table.AddCell(new Cell().SetHeight(MIN_HEIGHT).SetKeepTogether(true)).

Also it doesn't work for cell content:
table.AddCell(new Cell().Add(new Paragraph().SetHeight(MIN_HEIGHT).SetKeepTogether(true)))

Comment: I guess I should add AreaBreak only when available space on page is less than "header + first row" height? Is it possible to check available space?

Comment: Actually, `setKeepTogether(true)` should work on cells and there are a lot of tests where it does. You can check that yourself if you want (`TableTest#simpleTableTest11`). However, you did not post your code so that is impossible to guess on which side the things went wrong.

Comment: To check current free space, you can use `doc.getRenderer().getCurrentArea().getBBox();`

Comment: I added repro that shows that setKeepTogether() doesn't work.

Comment: It indeed was an edge case bug of min-height and keepTogether combination. Already fixed in Java `7.0.3.-SNAPSHOT`. Will take a while to be ported to C#.

Comment: As a workaround for the current version, you probably can set MinHeight to a Paragraph and add that paragraph as a child to the Cell.

Comment: Thank you! To be clear, this is not only min-height bug, height + keepTogether also breaks. Unfortunately, child paragraph with minHeight and keepTogether breaks too. But I think I can replace minHeight with couple blank lines at the end of the first cell at each row.

Comment: FYI the header splitting problem has also been fixed in the `7.0.3-SNAPSHOT` Java version.

Answer (score 0):

set the table header cells. `tbl.addHeaderCell( new Cell().add("head txt"));`
this will force the headers to repeat in new pages from my experiences.
then just add content in the cells for the columns like normal.